# Excel Viewer limits cells to 255 characters when copying

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2000

I am running MS Office 2000. I needed to open and work with a xlsx file. I tried to install the Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack and it didn't work. So I installed the newest Excel viewer.

The viewer opens the file correctly and I can only view and copy. I tried copying the data from the viewer to an Excel 2000 document. When I do that it copies all the cells. However, it will truncate any cell that is longer than 255 characters long.

Why is it truncating data longer than 255 characters? Is there a way to prevent the truncation?

Comment: according to this page. https://sites.google.com/a/elixirtech.com/wiki/repertoire/data/excel-datasource/excel-worksheet-limit... 256 is a limitation for very old versions

Comment: I just created an Excel 2000 document and entered a bunch of text into just one cell. I copied that text from that cell and did a character count. The result was 1568 characters. So, Excel 2000 can clearly hold more than 255 characters in a given cell.